# Insert an input into database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert in my database the input provided by the user, alongside the id . However i'm failing to do so. Maybe i'm way off maybe i'm close, but I just want to learn how to do it.Any help please?

```
$options = '';
    $filter=mysql_query("select id from employees WHERE Status='Employed '");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($filter)) {
        $options .="<option>" . $row['id'] . "</option>";
    }
    $menu="<form id='filter' name='filter' method='post' action=''>
    id : <select name='filter' id='filter' style='color:grey;'>" . $options . "</select>
    hours: <input type='text' name='Hours' style=' padding: 10px;border: solid 2px #c9c9c9; width:50px; height:2px;'>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' style='width:80px; height:30px; text-align:center; padding:0px;'>
    </form>
    <br>
    ";


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

  $hours = $_POST['Hours'];
  $sql="INSERT INTO `editedworkhours` (`id`, `Note`, `WH`, `DeductedWH`) VALUES('$options',NULL,'$ahours',NULL)";
}
echo $menu;
```

Comment: I would recommend not u sing`mysql_*` statements as they are deprecated, and also where are you executing your `$sql` statement? You could try out `PDO` having a OOP interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is mistake in your if condition

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $addedhours = //fetched variable from the post data
        $options    = //fetched variable from the post data
             $sql="INSERT INTO `editedworkhours` (`AFNumber`, `Note`, `AddedWH`, `DeductedWH`) VALUES('$options',NULL,'$addedhours',NULL)";
             $getResult =mysql_query($sql);
             if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
             {
                   // do something
             } 
             else{
                   // do something
             }
     }
```

If you wish to insert only in selected fields then you can remove the extra fields from your query. Like...

```
   $sql="INSERT INTO `editedworkhours` (`AFNumber`,`AddedWH`) VALUES('$options','$addedhours')";
```

And make sure all variables are not blank.. you can debug the query. Like...

```
   echo $sql; 
   exit;
```

and copy that query, paste it into SQL area and check it. Whether it return any data or not.

Good Luck ['}

Comment: what does the if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0)
             {
                   // do something
             } 
             else{
                   // do something
             } part suppose to do?

Comment: it will return affected rows by last query that's our insert query, and you can manage the action or give some  relevant  reply to user whether it inserted successfully or not. ['}

Comment: I'm still not being able to insert.

Comment: according to my aboc post, isn't $options the current id selected?

Comment: check I edited for you and trace your code as per you need you will get your answer my friend...

Comment: i know php doesn't work on jsfiddle, but here's my code : http://jsfiddle.net/8uLm420v/

Comment: if you have time please tell me where did i go wrong

Comment: by echoing the sql, it's taking the whole list of ids, and not the slected one in the list

Comment: Oh man for get the selected item you just have to write $_POST['<name>'] and in your code the name of select box and name of form tag are same please change it..  and make sure about option also about options. Like ...

     <option value="<employee data> " > </option>

Answer (score 0):

Apart from (among other problems) the fact that you really, really should not use mysql_* functions any more:
Near the end of your snippet you create a query. But you never execute it. That's why it's not working.